# Cannot read property of undefined Javascript and underscore.js

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I am using underscore.js to find specific data in JSON. The data is returned as an object but when I try to read the "Date" property I get undefined. However, I can take that same string of data and create a new object and access the Date just find. What am I doing wrong?

```
var Activities = [{
    "Place": "Home",
    "Activities": [{
        "Date": "2014-11-28T00:00:00",
        "Activities": [{
            "TV": "Show",
            "Eat": "Show",
            "HadFun": false
        }]
    }, {
        "Date": "2014-12-01T00:00:00",
        "Activities": [{
            "TV": "Show",
            "Eat": "Show",
            "HadFun": false
        }, {
            "TV": "Show",
            "Eat": "Show",
            "HadFun": false
        }, {
            "TV": "Show",
            "Eat": "Show",
            "HadFun": false
        }, {
            "TV": "Show",
            "Eat": "Show",
            "HadFun": false
        }, {
            "TV": "Show",
            "Eat": "Show",
            "HadFun": false
        }]
    }]
}];

_.each(Activities, function (item) {
    _.each(item, function (Activities) {
        var found = _.where(Activities, {
            Date: "2014-11-28T00:00:00"
        });
        console.log(found[0].Date);

        var t = [{
            "Date": "2014-11-28T00:00:00",
            "Activities": [{
                "TV": "Show",
                "Eat": "Show",
                "HadFun": false
            }]
        }];
        console.log(t[0].Date);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you go through Activities you are iterating over the array with one object.

Then the next each starts by iterating over that objects properties. First it iterates over `Place` and so finds no object with a Date property matching that value. When the second each goes over Activities it then finds the value

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/fbmwrLxz/

```
// loops Activities array
_.each(Activities, function (item) {
    // First loop loops once since Place is just a string value
    // Second loop loops twice since Activities has two objects
    _.each(item, function (Activities) {
        var found = _.where(Activities, {
            Date: "2014-11-28T00:00:00"
        });

        if (found[0]) {
            console.log(found[0].Date);
        }

        var t = [{
            "Date": "2014-11-28T00:00:00",
            "Activities": [{
                "TV": "Show",
                "Eat": "Show",
                "HadFun": false
            }]
        }];
        console.log(t[0].Date);
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle showing what happens a bit more clearly by printing out each iteration: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/fbmwrLxz/1/

Answer (score 1):

`found` contains an array of the objects that match:

`var found = _.where(Activities[0].Activities, { Date: "2014-11-28T00:00:00" });`

outputs

```
[{"Date":"2014-11-28T00:00:00","Activities":[{"TV":"Show","Eat":"Show","HadFun":false}]}]
```